# ReadStringAsSync() Returning part of the content only

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

I have a simple ASP.NET Core 2.2 Controller action that returns incomplete JSON even when sent a request from POSTMAN.

The code runs fine until I include the navigation property for related entity "Books". The results are returned correctly from the ToList() method on the IQueryable object, as I can see when debugging. But, for some reason, when the ReadAsStringAsync() runs, it returns only part of the expected JSON result.

Below is the code for the API:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/TestEntity/ListTest")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TestEntityPerson>>> ListTest()
    {
        var query = _context.Persons
            .Include(p => p.Books)
            .AsQueryable().Take(5);
        var results = await Task.FromResult(Json(query.ToList()));
        return results;
    }
```

And the result I receive (which is only a part of the expected result) in the client is:

```
[{"$type":"Identica.My.Bonus.Entities.TestEntityPerson, Identica.My.Bonus","name":"Susan","balance":240749.08345506949,"age":56,"books":[{"$type":"Identica.My.Bonus.Entities.TestEntityBook, Identica.My.Bonus","title":"SRWZLSRKQNYKPY","author":"VEJZP","price":13.334878714911119,"personId":"f24dbe36-1f99-4a59-3cb7-08d6c4048ace"
```

Any pointers on what I could try to solve this problem? I couldn't find any relevant questions on stack overflow.

**EDIT: This happens only when there is a navigational property on the related entity pointing back at the original entity. When I removed this property, the problem was gone.**

And this is the client code:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to run query...");
        Console.Read();

        MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue mediaTypeJson = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");

        List<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters = new List<MediaTypeFormatter> {
            new JsonMediaTypeFormatter {
                SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
                }
            }
        };

        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44359/") })
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(mediaTypeJson);

            Expression<Func<TestEntityPerson, bool>> expressionFilter =
                t => (t.Balance > 240000 || t.Age < 25) && 
                (t.Books == null || t.Books.Any(b => b.Price < 7 || b.Title.StartsWith('A')));

            var filterNode = expressionFilter.ToExpressionNode();

            Expression<Func<IQueryable<TestEntityPerson>, IOrderedQueryable<TestEntityPerson>>> expressionOrderBy = t => t.OrderByDescending(x => x.Balance);

            var orderByNode = expressionOrderBy.ToExpressionNode();

            Pagination pagination = new Pagination() { Start = 0, Limit = 10 };

            QueryOptionsNodes queryOptions = new QueryOptionsNodes()
            {
                FilterExpressionNode = filterNode,
                SortingExpressionNode = orderByNode,
                Pagination = pagination
            };

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sending request...");

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/TestEntity/List", queryOptions, formatters[0], mediaTypeJson, CancellationToken.None);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                Console.WriteLine("Reading Response request...");

                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<TestEntityPerson>>(formatters, CancellationToken.None);
                ShowEntities(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            try
            {
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");

        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ShowEntities(IEnumerable<TestEntityPerson> testEntities)
    {
        foreach (var entity in testEntities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}) {1} Age = {2} Balance = {3}", entity.Id, entity.Name, entity.Age, entity.Balance);
            if (entity.Books != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Books:");
                foreach (var book in entity.Books)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-- {0}) {1} Price = {2}", book.Id, book.Title, book.Price);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using `var response = await HttpClient...` using Wait might end up closing the connection before you retrieve the data you want.

Comment: I tried it now, but still same problem.

Comment: Before proceeding any further can you use postman or a similar app to inspect the response ?

Comment: Do you know how I can add formatters to postman request? It won't work by default options. Because I'm using library Serialize.Linq and I need to set up the http client as in above code.

Comment: I suppose this can by done by either content type and accept type headers

Comment: I tried with postman and still same problem.

Comment: Just a FYI, because the only place you are getting your tasks from is `Task.FromResult` you can just get rid of the `async Task<` portion of the method signature and just have it return `Json(query.ToList())`. There is no point of returning a task if you are not going to do any actual async operations in the method.

Comment: Also, could you post the client code you are using? I know you tested it with postman but I would like to see the client code too.

Comment: added the client code

Answer (score 0):

The problem that there was an unnecessary navigational property on the "related entity" pointing back at the "original entity".

```
public class TestEntityPerson : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Balance { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public List<TestEntityBook> Books { get; set; }
}
```

And the related entity:

```
public class TestEntityBook : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public Guid TestEntityPersonId { get; set; }

    // The problematic property
    public TestEntityPerson TestEntityPerson { get; set; }
}
```

When I removed the TestEntityPerson property from the Book entity, the problem was solved.

**EDIT: I suppose this is not a real solution, since it should be OK to have inverse navigation properties, but in this case it was causing a problem.**

Comment: There are settings on JSON output formatters that deal with this kind of cycle references

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of this setting.